# Background Location does not work in android 11

Tags: c#, xamarin, geolocation, android-permissions

I have a mobile application written in Xamarin and the class that ask for permission looks like this

```
 public class AppPermissionsManager
    {
        private readonly string[] _permissions =
        {
            Manifest.Permission.AccessCoarseLocation,
            Manifest.Permission.AccessFineLocation,
            Manifest.Permission.AccessLocationExtraCommands,
            Manifest.Permission.AccessNetworkState,
            Manifest.Permission.AccessWifiState,
            Manifest.Permission.Camera,
            Manifest.Permission.Internet,
            Manifest.Permission.ReadPhoneState,
            Manifest.Permission.ReadExternalStorage,
            Manifest.Permission.WriteExternalStorage
        };

        private readonly string[] _androidQPermissions =
        {
            Manifest.Permission.AccessCoarseLocation,
            Manifest.Permission.AccessFineLocation,
            Manifest.Permission.AccessLocationExtraCommands,
            Manifest.Permission.AccessNetworkState,
            Manifest.Permission.AccessWifiState,
            Manifest.Permission.Camera,
            Manifest.Permission.Internet,
            Manifest.Permission.ReadPhoneState,
            Manifest.Permission.ReadExternalStorage,
            Manifest.Permission.WriteExternalStorage,
            Manifest.Permission.AccessBackgroundLocation
        };

        public static int RequestLocationId = 0;

        public bool CheckPermissions()
        {
            string[] permissions = GetPermissions();

            foreach (var permission in permissions)
            {
                if (ContextCompat.CheckSelfPermission(Android.App.Application.Context, permission) != (int)Permission.Granted)
                {
                    return false;
                }
            }

            return true;
        }

        private string[] GetPermissions()
        {
            return Android.OS.Build.VERSION.SdkInt >= Android.OS.BuildVersionCodes.Q ? _androidQPermissions : _permissions;
        }

        public void RequestPermissions()
        {
            try
            {
                var permissions = GetPermissions();

                Activity activity = CrossCurrentActivity.Current.Activity;
                ActivityCompat.RequestPermissions(activity, permissions, RequestLocationId);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                LoggingHelper.LogError(ex, nameof(AppPermissionsManager), MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name);
            }
        }
    }
```

My problem is that AccessBackgroundLocation does not work on Android 11 (when the user opens the app, a blank page appears and no error is logged). If I remove the AccessBackgroundLocation, the app works fine (except for the background location functionality)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Background Location Restrictions Android 11+ API 30+](https://developer.android.com/training/location/permissions#java)

In order to access background location user must enable permissions from Settings page.

**EDIT**

With the help of @lee-m in the comments, the answer to your question is that in Android 11+, when you ask for Foreground and Background location at the same time, android will ignore this request and will not grant permission for either one.

Firstly you need Foreground location access, and then Backgroud. If you really need Background location you need to prompt your user to enable Allow all the time from the Settings page of your Application.

Comment: According to that link, Android is ignoring the requests since OP is requesting both foreground and background location at the same time rather than anything related to actions the user needs to perform.

Comment: @lee-m In my understanding android will ignore Access to Background Location until the user goes to the Settings page of the Application and provides the permission Allow all the time. Please correct me if i'm wrong.

Comment: OP is already requesting the permissions, so the fact that the user has to go and manually grant them implies the original request from within the code isn't working. If you look at that link it says "If you request a foreground location permission and the background location permission at the same time, the system ignores the request and doesn't grant your app either permission." - and since OP is requesting foreground and background location at the same, this appears to be what's happening.

Comment: Indeed, you are correct. I misunderstood this point. So the correct approach would be ask for Foreground Location and then separately the Background.

Comment: "If you really need Background location you need to prompt your user to enable Allow all the time from the Settings page of your Application." - is that something that is done automatic or I should do a redirect from my app?

Comment: According to the documentation: The system dialog doesn't include the Allow all the time option. Instead, users must enable background location on a settings page. 
You can help users navigate to this settings page by following best practices when requesting the background location permission. I guess your next step is to figure out how to guide the user to Allow location access all the time. But no, it's not automatic.